Manage account member subscriptions using APS's APIs
Is there a way to manage the subscriptions of account members using one of the available APS's RESTful APIs? I've reviewed the available API endpoints under the account users section in the Autodesk Construction Cloud APIs documentation, but I haven’t found any parameters or options that allow subscription management for account members.
Thank you in advance.
Screenshot1_Project memberScreenshot2_JSON response (project member products)Screenshot3_Account user

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Look at the ACC Account Admin API, specifically at the PATCH projects/{projectId}/users/{userId} endpoint. This might give you what you're looking for?


Thank you Petr Broz for your reply!
My aim is actually to manage the information of "account" users rather than project members. I've updated my question and added more screenshots to provide more clarity.
As you can see in the first and second screenshots, the products I get are the ones assigned to a project member. However, I would like to be able to add the products assigned to the "account" user (member subscriptions) (see screenshot 3). I’ve already identified the endpoint for creating a new account member:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/users-POST/

However, it seems there's no method to assign member subscriptions to account users via this endpoint. Is there a workaround for this scenario?

Ah I see. I'm afraid we don't support this kind of setup at the account level.

I have tried something interesting...I have used the network activity monitor in Chrome's developer tool to observe the responsible API call made whenever a member's subscription was updated manually in Autodesk ACC.
I could find the following API call:

curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id/offerings' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer someaccesstokengeneratedinsideACCwebsite' 
-H 'Region: EMEA' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Accept: /' 
-H 'Origin: https://acc.autodesk.eu' 
--data-raw '{"offeringExternalKey":"SO-4156"}' 
--compressed

whereas account_id is our hub id, :user_id is a specific user id and the access token is the one generated automatically during the subscription updating process inside the ACC UI.
I imported this request in postman and it worked perfectly!
However, when I replaced the access token with one generated using the regular client ID and client secret, I received the following error:
{
"status": 403,
"type": "",
"id": "b7658f818a28fa5e",
"title": "Forbidden",
"detail": "Route not enabled for clientId"
}

Is it actually a special access token? Do you think it’s possible to dynamically generate an access token that would work for this specific API call?

Yep, it's possible that this is an internal/undocumented endpoint that is limited to a specific client ID or scope.
